# RestSharp addfile sends file with ".undefined" file extension

Tags: c#, restsharp

I'm uploading PDF file to node.js server with code below:

```
var file = new FileContentResult(...)
var client = new RestClient(_tenantOptions.BaseUrl + _tenantOptions.UploadPdfFilesUrn) {Timeout = _tenantOptions.RequestTimeoutMilliseconds};
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("Authorization", accessToken);
request.AddFile("file", file.FileContents, file.ContentType);
var response = client.Execute<UploadFileResponse>(request);
```

This file appears on server like `filename.undefined` though `file.ContentType = "application/pdf"`. What did I miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the source code for RestSharp](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/blob/10d8aa9712175627daaec1787c0a9566fddd7bcc/src/RestSharp/RestRequest.cs#L188-L189) there's a 4-parameter form of `AddFile` that accepts the filename too.

Try

```
request.AddFile("file", file.FileContents, "document.pdf", file.ContentType);
```